# angular api contact forms security

Tags: php, angular, email, spam, spam-prevention

In angular, I am doing a api call when the user submit's a contact-formular. Then my idea was that the api should send a post request to the server-side with all the credentials and execute a php mail command.

Only one problem here. This leaves a security risk. If user grab the api informations from the client-side and then manually do a post request with the above informations, the user can spam the mail service.

So. How do we secure this process? reCapcha could be an idea. But what if the user also grab the response from reCapche and send that manually with the post request? Then it's not secure again.

How do we secure our web forms properly in the client side to server side?

**api-mailto typescript:**

```
mailTo(name: string, email: string, message: string) {

    const formData = new URLSearchParams();

    formData.set('name', name);
    formData.set('email', email);
    formData.set('message', message);

    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    };

    return this.httpClient.post(this.rootUrl + 'custom/mail', formData.toString(), options);
  }
```

**Server site mailservice:**

```
private function mailService()
  {
    $errors = [];

    if(!isset($request['name']) || $request['name'] == ''){
      $errors[] = "Name is empty";
    }

    //Validation continues...

    if(count($errors) === 0){
      $this->mailExec($request['email'], ($request['subject']) ? $request['subject'] : 'Besked fra: Simonduun.com', $request['message']);
      return true;
    }

    return $errors;

  }
```

Comment: did you add validation for contact form?